# Viewing vertices in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, vertices

In ArcGIS, is it possible to change the polyline symbology to show vertices? Or do I need to extract the points via [Feature Vertices To Points](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Feature%20Vertices%20to%20Points%20(Data%20Management))? This becomes a pain if I want to edit the source polygon/polyline features.

Here is what I'd like to see (this is from GMS), as I can clearly see start/end nodes and interior vertices.

[image: Linestring]

I [found out](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0705/files/editips.pdf) that pressing the <kbd>V</kbd> key while editing will show vertices. But it is only useful while editing and pressing <kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: Yes the only was to maintain polyline and vertices consistency is in the editing mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the free [draw vertices](http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoTools/UserGuide/ETDrawVertices.htm) tool from Ian Ko's geowizards. Works very nicely.

Answer (score 3):

There is an example in the SDK samples
http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/COM/ExtendAO/VertexLineSymbol.htm

**Description**
This project provides a custom symbol to draw a line and its vertices. Simple custom functionality is provided to alter both the symbol used to draw the basic shape of the line, and the symbol used to draw its vertices. A property page is also provided to allow users to edit the properties of the symbol using the user interface.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend that you vote for an ArcGIS Idea entitled [Draw vertices](https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/1681):

> It would be nice to display vertices at all time. Currently a line has
>   to be selected for it to draw vertices. Maybe a button to turn it on
>   and off.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way to do this OOTB, but in the past I've handled this requirement with a layerextension.  The extension would draw vertices when [ILayerExtensionDraw.AfterLayerDraw](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000732000000) was called.  This requires ArcObjects though.