# Is there a line symbology that also shows vertices?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, symbology

**Is there such a thing as a line/vertices symbology?** If not a workaround? In some situations, particularly when editing, I would like to see my lines as well as all the vertices similar to the effect I get when using the Edit Vertices tool but on all features in the feature class not just the selected feature.

The solution should be dynamic, without having to create a separate point layer but having one line features class loaded twice in the TOC is acceptable.

Programmatic solution using an example (addin, ArcObjects & VB.Net) is acceptable.

I have the ArcEditor license in case there is a trick to use with representations.

Comment: This was answered for ArcGIS 9.3, which doesn't necessarily mean that it works for ArcGIS 10:

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7805/view-vertices-in-arcgis

I don't know if these techniques still apply, but you could give them a shot and report back which ones (if any) work. It's a place to start.

Comment: Lou's answer still works at 10.0

Comment: I know pressing V while editing still works in 10.0. You can also use the "Feature Vertices to Points" tool in the "Data Management Toolbox" to convert your lines vertices to points then overlay them with your line feature for display.

Comment: I don't believe this can be done in any easy way. There is a ArcGIS forum on this topic here: [Forum Link](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=982&t=58018&g=1)

The forum is dated 2002, but it does have a VBA module which may be able to do the trick for you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have  ArcEditor or ArcInfo license level you can your **Cartograpic Representations** to show vertices.

You can use maker (= point symbol) on top of a line to show all vertices. See option **on vertices** in [ArcGIS Help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/List_of_marker_placement_styles/008t00000010000000/):

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Good idea. I did ask for a trick with representations so I will mark this as answered. (I do have ArcEditor but to be honest though I am not a big fan of cartographic representations.) I will probably not go trough the trouble of exporting lines to representations unless I am doing a big job.

Answer (score 1):

For the fun of it. I placed point layer on a top of table of content (vertices) and named layer to extract vertices from "line". I inserted this labeling expression to another slave layer with single feature:

```
lyr,points ="line","vertices"
arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management("vertices")
curT = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(points,"Shape@")
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr, "SHAPE@"):
  shp=row[0]
  for part in shp:
    for pnt in part:
      pG=arcpy.PointGeometry(pnt)
      if pnt: curT.insertRow((pG,))
def FindLabel ( ):
  return ""
```

It is enough to switch visibility of slave layer twice to make vertices appear. That is much faster than using script attached to a tool. It honors selection yey!