# Displaying Vertices and Nodes in ArcGIS Desktop when editing?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, topology, vertices

A previous employee built a custom tool for users in our organization that displays nodes and vertices when editing. Essentially the purpose is:

```
The Display Topology Nodes button will symbolize the Topology Nodes of the active
(selected) Feature Class in a Map Topology depending on the number of line segments that share that node.

The Display Vertices button will display the vertices of the active (selected) layer in the Table of Contents.
Nodes will be portrayed as such:

RED = End Node
PURPLE = Where two (2) features intersect

CYAN = Where three (3) features intersect

GREEN = Where four (4) features intersect

MAGENTA = Where five (5) features intersect

YELLOW = Where six (6) features intersect
```

Is there a built in tool using ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.1 that will provide this functionality?

I am getting a little pushback on upgrading these users and I need to provide this service, however, it looks like the tool as it is now, does not work on 10.2.1.

Comment: Would this be answered by this questions (might be a possible workaround): https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24159/is-there-a-line-symbology-that-also-shows-vertices

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @Martin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82578/vertex-and-nodes-tool-migrating-from-9-3-1-to-10-2-1#comment113864_82578):

> I usually just press "V" on the keyboard to show vertexes, when in edit mode

This is documented on the [Keyboard shortcuts that can be used while editing](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/keyboard-shortcuts-that-can-be-used-while-editing.htm) page.