# Showing vertices outside editing session in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, vertices

Does anybody know, if it is possible to see features' vertices (or all) when you are not in editing mode?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24159/is-there-a-line-symbology-that-also-shows-vertices

Comment: you mean, convert polygon or polyline to vertices?